# How to divide page into 6 parts?

Tags: tables, graphics, pdftex

How to divide a page into 6 parts? I would like to place 1 table and 5 figures in 3x2 arrangement. Are mini pages necessary, or is there something more effective? Thank you so much.

```
\documentclass[landscape,11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={275mm,190mm},
 left=10mm,
 top=10mm,
 }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Time interval    &  s     \\
45               & g      \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{fig1.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{fig2.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{fig3.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{fig4.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{fig5.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages indepdently from each other, as happens when `\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}` is run. To maximize the interoperability of the packages, simply run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: Problem solved? If yes, consider accepting on of the provided answers.

Answer (score 1):

An option to flexibility and accurately align objects is using the package `tikz` (in three steps).

As a first step you define six nodes as `\node (<name>) {<object>};`, where `<object>` is a text or a tabular or a figure ...,

then add their relative position `\node (<name>) [<position>] {<object>};` using for position a syntax like `right = of <name of other node>` or `below= of ...`

Finally, define the size of the nodes (`minimum size=`) and change the default value of their spacings to fit on the page (`node distance=`).

You can compile the document after each step to see the progress.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    landscape,
    a4paper,
    total={275mm,190mm},
    left=10mm,
    bottom=20mm,
}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}% needed <<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{document}
  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[minimum size=0.25\linewidth, node distance=-1.0cm and 0.5cm ]%first parameter is the vertical node distance and the second is the horizontal node distance
        \node  (Ini) {%
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
                Time interval    &  s     \\
                45               & g      \\
                \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
        \end{tabular}};
        \node  (Im1)[right= of Ini] {\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
        \node  (Im2)[below= of Ini] {\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
        \node  (Im3)[below= of Im1] {\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
        \node  (Im4)[below= of Im2] {\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
        \node  (Im5)[below= of Im3] {\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `tabular` and a single `table` or `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cc}
% the table
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
Time interval    &  s     \\
\midrule
45               & g      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
& 
% the top right picture
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\\
\addlinespace
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
&
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\\
\addlinespace
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
&
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a package that solves this problem more easily than using `minipage`s or any other tab-related constructs. I am not aware of such a package.

In following answer I assumed you would have something like an equally sized grid of 3x2 number of cells.

This solution is based on a tabulated structure. The `X` column from `tabularx` equally divides the table. In order to force fixed height, I also added `parbox`. Each cell can have text and images as if in a regular paragraph.

The only issue is a mix of texts with images in `tabular`-like environments causes a text to be pushed towards the bottom of an image. One way to overcome it is to use `\raisebox{}{}`; perhaps not the best but it's working.

The code below also has a couple of macros for easier usage

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\ctext[1]{%
    \parbox[t][0.33\textheight]{\linewidth}{#1}}
\newcommand\cimage[1]{%
    \parbox[t][0.33\textheight]{\linewidth}{%
      \centering%
      \raisebox{-\dimexpr(\totalheight-10pt)}{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X X@{}}
    \ctext{%
      A regular paragraph.

      A list:
      \begin{itemize}
        \item with
        \item a few
        \item items.
      \end{itemize}

      Followed by another text.} &
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}} \\
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}} &
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}} \\
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}} &
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-golden}}
\end{tabularx}

\clearpage
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X X@{}}
    \ctext{%
        \centering A centred\\multi-lined text.

        \vspace{3ex}Small images} &
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}} \\
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-c}} &
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image}} \\
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}} &
    \cimage{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-golden}}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```